# Wicket 7 WebSocketBehavior

Tags: websocket, wicket

I am developing extending WebSocketBehavior in order to send logging data to a client..  have generated the logging handler and it fires as and when needed.

I am having trouble understanding how exactly to push the log entries to the clients and update the console panel.  I already know the onMessage method is what I need to override with the console taking the WeSocketRequestHandler as an argument along with the message I want to send.  How exactly do I get the onMessage to fire properly??  Here is the code I am using:

```
public class LogWebSocketBehavior extends WebSocketBehavior {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Console console;
private Handler logHandler;
private Model model;

public LogWebSocketBehavior(Console console) {
    super();
    configureLogger();
    this.console = console;
}

private void configureLogger() {
    Logger l = Logger.getLogger(AppUtils.loggerName);
    logHandler = getLoggerHandler();
    l.addHandler(logHandler);

}

@Override
protected void onMessage(WebSocketRequestHandler handler, TextMessage message) {
    console.info(handler, model.getObject());
}

private Handler getLoggerHandler() {
    return new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void publish(LogRecord record) {
            model.setObject(record);
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws SecurityException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    };
}
 private Collection<IWebSocketConnection> getConnectedClients() {
    IWebSocketConnectionRegistry registry = new SimpleWebSocketConnectionRegistry();
    return registry.getConnections(getApplication());
}

private void sendToAllConnectedClients(String message) {
    Collection<IWebSocketConnection> wsConnections = getConnectedClients();
    for (IWebSocketConnection wsConnection : wsConnections) {
        if (wsConnection != null && wsConnection.isOpen()) {
            try {
                wsConnection.sendMessage("test");
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The logger works as I want it to, providing messages as needed, but I cannot find how to actually fire the onMessage method to update my console.  Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

`#onMessage()` is called by Wicket whenever the browser pushes a message via `Wicket.WebSocket.send("some message")`.

It is not very clear but I guess you need to push messages from the server to the clients (the browsers). If this is the case then you need to get a handle to IWebSocketRequestHandler and use its `#push(String)` method. You can do this with `WebSocketSettings.Holder.get(Application.get()).getConnectionRegistry().getConnection(...).push("message")`.

Comment: I've just added exactly what you're talking about.  Still, the onMessage method is not firing.

Comment: Thank you, you got me on the right path.  Here is the behavior that functions basically the way I need:

Answer (score 0):

Here is the class working as I need.  Thank you Martin!!

public class LogWebSocketBehavior extends WebSocketBehavior {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Console console;
private Handler logHandler;
private IModel model;

public LogWebSocketBehavior(Console console, IModel model) {
    super();
    configureLogger();
    this.console = console;
    this.model = model;
}

private void configureLogger() {
    Logger l = Logger.getLogger(AppUtils.loggerName);
    logHandler = getLoggerHandler();
    l.addHandler(logHandler);

}

@Override
protected void onPush(WebSocketRequestHandler handler, IWebSocketPushMessage message) {
    super.onPush(handler, message);
    console.info(handler, model);
}

private Handler getLoggerHandler() {
    return new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void publish(LogRecord record) {
            model.setObject(record);
            sendToAllConnectedClients(record.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws SecurityException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    };
}

private Collection<IWebSocketConnection> getConnectedClients() {
    IWebSocketConnectionRegistry registry = new SimpleWebSocketConnectionRegistry();
    return registry.getConnections(getApplication());
}

private void sendToAllConnectedClients(String message) {

    IWebSocketConnectionRegistry registry = new SimpleWebSocketConnectionRegistry();

    WebSocketPushBroadcaster b = new WebSocketPushBroadcaster(registry);
    IWebSocketPushMessage msg = new Message();
    b.broadcastAll(getApplication(), msg);

}

class Message implements IWebSocketPushMessage {

    public Message(){

    }

}
```

}